# Disable SSH for non root users

Tags: ssh, remote-access

How do i disable remote access for non-root users over ssh? i would like to do this on demand if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everyone is doing this the hard way.. he said deny for all non-root users.. so just edit

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Add the following

```
AllowGroups wheel root
```

Then restart ssh

Anyone in the wheel or root group will be allowed to ssh in

Comment: he said 'on demand'

Answer (score 4):

Several possibilities:

- `/bin/false` as login shell for the normal users in /etc/passwd
- Add only root to `AllowUsers` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: /bin/false in /etc/passwd would also disable local access.

Answer (score 1):

Can use PAM as well:
    `cp /etc/security/access.conf /etc/security/sshd.conf`
    `echo "+ : root : ALL" >> /etc/security/sshd.conf`
    `echo "- : ALL : ALL" >> /etc/security/sshd.conf`

Then modify /etc/pam.d/sshd to add the following line after the other accounts:
`account    required     pam_access.so  accessfile=/etc/security/sshd.conf`

This will also allow you to restrict by network if you decide to do so in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be on-demand, the standard way is to use `/etc/nologin` (have a look at `man 5 nologin`).

Creating this file (with an optional message inside) will deny non-admin logins and display the message instead; removing the file will allow logins back.

It can be applied to ssh, local logins, and anything else that uses PAM; just make sure that
the PAM configuration for the service requires `pam_nologin.so`. (It does by default for ssh and console logins on many distributions)